# trying to get the function def getLowestTemp(): to work..it pulls up the highest temp...I already have that function working

Tags: python

```
#import statements
import os.path

#define global variables
database = []#list to store monthly temperatures
DAYS = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
WEEKS = 6


def getInputFromFile(filename = None):
    result = False
    if(filename == None):
        filename = input("Enter name of input file: ")
    if(os.path.isfile(filename)):
        infile = open(filename, 'r')
        count = 0
        for line in infile:
            week = line.strip()
            weekList = week.split()
            database.append(weekList)
            count += 1
        infile.close()
        return True
    else:
        print("Invalid filename ... aborting ...")

    return False




def getDayAverages():
    dayAverages = []
    MAX = WEEKS
    for day in range(len(DAYS)):
        total = 0
        for week in range (WEEKS):
            total += int(database[week][day])
        dayAverages.append(total/WEEKS)
    return dayAverages

def getWeekAverages():
    pass
    weekAverages = []
    MAX = WEEKS
    total = 0

    for week in range (WEEKS):
            total = 0
            for day in range(len(DAYS)):
              total += int(database[week][day])
            weekAverages.append(total/7)
    return weekAverages

def getHighestDayAverages(dayAverages):
    average = max(dayAverages)
    return average



def getLowestDayAverages(dayAverages):
    average = min(dayAverages)
    return average




def getHighestWeekAverages(weekAverages):
    average = max(weekAverages)
    return average



def getLowestWeekAverages(weekAverages):
    average = min(weekAverages)
    return average
```

this works
    def getHighestTemp():
        highestTemp = int(database[0][0])
        for week in range (WEEKS):
            for day in range(len(DAYS)):
                if highestTemp < int(database[week][day]):
                    highestTemp = int(database[week][day])
        return highestTemp

here is where I am having problems: getLowestTemp

```
def getLowestTemp():
    lowestTemp = int(database[0][0])
    for week in range (WEEKS):
        for day in range(len(DAYS)):
            if lowestTemp < int(database[week][day]):
                lowestTemp = int(database[week][day])
    return lowestTemp



def main():
    goodFile = getInputFromFile("julywilm.txt")
    if(goodFile == True):
        dayAverages = getDayAverages()
        weekAverages = getWeekAverages()
        highestDay = getHighestDayAverages(dayAverages)
        lowestDay = getLowestDayAverages(dayAverages)
        highestWeek = getHighestWeekAverages(weekAverages)
        lowestWeek = getLowestWeekAverages(weekAverages)
        highestTemp = getHighestTemp()
        lowestTemp = getLowestTemp

        print(dayAverages)

        print(weekAverages)

        dayIndex = dayAverages.index(highestDay)
        print(DAYS[dayIndex], 'with',getHighestDayAverages(dayAverages))

        dayIndex = dayAverages.index(lowestDay)
        print(DAYS[dayIndex], 'with', getLowestDayAverages(dayAverages))


        print(getHighestWeekAverages(weekAverages))


        print(getLowestWeekAverages(weekAverages))
        print(getHighestTemp())
        print(getLowestTemp())




main()
```

here is the actual text file.
70 74 104 57 78 65 96 
82 67 100 43 60 57 93 
66 75 90 78 64 72 73 
86 93 64 109 79 70 44 
81 72 95 0000 0000 0000 0000 
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
July    2014    Wilmington North Carolina

Answer (score 0):

In "if lowestTemp < int(database[week][day]):" your "<" should be an ">".

Comment: when I made that change before, it gives me a zero..I listed the text file just now

Comment: That's because of all the 0000 entries in your text file. If you, for example, change your WEEKS value to 4, so you're not reading the last two weeks which contain 0000's, then the lowest temperature will be 43, but if you do read the weeks with 0000's in them, yeah, the lowest temperature will be 0.

Comment: def getAverageTemp():
    averageTemp = int(database[0][0])
    for week in range (WEEKS):
        for day in range(len(DAYS)):
            if averageTemp == int(database[week][day]):
                averageTemp = int(database[week][day])
    return averageTemp
how I am trying to get the average........its not working

Comment: That's not how you get an average -- the comments here won't let me format code, but you need something more like this: http://pastebin.com/hhJqdrB9

Comment: File "Homework1b.py", line 110
    total += int(database[week][day]):
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You shouldn't have a colon at the end of that line -- look at the http://pastebin.com/hhJqdrB9 link I posted above.

Comment: Thank you so much.....How could I get the temps to be formatted to 2 decimal places

Comment: There are multiple ways to do it -- you could do a search and see more of them -- but here is one: Suppose you had a variable named "temp" which you wanted to be printed formatted to two decimal places, you could do print("{0:.2f}".format(temp))